UBUNTU-MATE 22.04 on NUC 7i5BNB has short black screen intervals with some kernels
I first remarked this behavior with kernel 6.5.0-40.
It was resolved with 6.5.0-45
But back with 6.8.0-45,47 and 48.
I know I should upgrade to UBUNTU-MATE 24.04 but I am afraid to lose the working setup with kernel 6.5.0-45.

Does anybody know a solution for this issue ?
Is there a way to revert to the working kernel after upgrading or installing to 24.04 ?

thx
UPDATE: a fresh install to 24.04 didn't change anything.

The GA kernel stack for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is 5.15; if you're having troubles with the newer kernels, why not use the GA kernel; Server installs default to that as its seen as more stable.  You tagged your question as relating to 22.04; but then mention 24.04; which uses newer 6.8(-6.11) kernels by default.  FYI:  Two Ubuntu-MATE 22.04 ISOs defaulted to GA kernel stack too as per flavor rules/custom

@guiverc: I use 22.04. Regular update/upgrade installed kernels 6.5.0 and later 6.8.0. I only mentioned 24.04 saying I did not upgrade to it.

The 6.5 kernel was from Ubuntu 23.10; with LTS releases having the choice of GA kernel (same for the entire life of the release; default for 22.04 & 22.04.1 Ubuntu-MATE installs) or HWE which updated to use 5.19 from 22.10, 6.2 from 23.04, 6.5 from 23.10 before finally setting on the GA stack from 24.04, ie. 6.8. Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't support 6.5 kernel as it was from the 23.10 release & users using the HWE stack upgraded to 6.8 on 23.10 reaching EOL. Supported kernels for 22.04 are now 5.15 (GA) or 6.8 (HWE) so using an unsupported 6.5 kernel is unwise if you're online!
